# Image bundle to test Lucene - Hibernate Search

Tags: lucene, hibernate-search

We are using Lucene in our electronical archive project. Since we do not have so many (image versions of) documents, we need some kind of image bundle to test lucene. I checked the internet but could not find with the above keywords. Does anyone know where this information can be found? Or what kind of keywords should I use?

Comment: What do you mean with "image" bundle? Do you mean you have actual images (eg gif or png) and want to extract text from them? In this case we are talking OCR software to extract text from images which you then feed to Lucene. Or maybe I misunderstand completely what you are after ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. First we have to make OCR of the images, then feed the results to Lucene. Because of the OCR thing, we need the image of docs..

Comment: Have you tried searching for something like "OCR test images"? Personally I would try to get test data though which matches your use case.

Comment: thanks for the comments.. it makes sense only for testing OCR, but not Lucene..

Comment: but the OCR part and Lucene part are completely orthogonal. You will have to come up with your own tool chain.